# Font face different size for specific unicode range (css 3 attribute) on different languages

Tags: css, font-face, unicode-range

I'm using font-face on my css and I have a problem that the hebrew char that create by using the src of the font-family that created by a designer and create another font-face with range to the english chars cause they are huge next to the hebrew chars on the same container.

here is my css code:

for any char:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MetaliRegular';
    src: url('../css/mmetaliregularwebfont.eot');
    src: url('../css/metaliregularwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../css/metaliregularwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../css/metaliregularwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../css/metaliregularwebfont.svg#MetaliRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and for the exceptions of the english chars,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MetaliRegular';
    src:  local("Arial");
    unicode-range: U+0041-007A; 
}
```

as you can see they have the same font-family.

I get them on different fonts, but the different between the sizes of the chars are huge.

Any help for this?

Thanks ,

Eran

Comment: Would [`font-size-adjust`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop) help?

Comment: No, sorry I tried this before and it's doesn't change the different between the fonts sizes..

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally best to use a single font for all languages if possible, e.g. for both Hebrew and Latin letters. One reason to this is the size issue: in different fonts, characters have different sizes (for the same font size), and this easily causes discrepancies when fonts are mixed. For example, in Arial Unicode MS, Hebrew letters have about the same height as Latin letters without ascenders or descenders (x, a, s, etc.) in the same font; in Times New Roman, they are somewhat taller.

If you really must mix fonts, you need to try to find matching fonts. Without knowing the characteristics of the MetaliRegular font, I can just suggest that you try and find a Web font that that matches it, for use with Latin letters.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
As I understand this is something that should be figure on the font files them selfs..By the way even the "Arial" fonts have major differences between the hebrew and the english fonts...